How to diagnose and resolve an undefined element reference in my JS
This is HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>PlanItt</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/style.css" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Comfortaa:wght@300..700&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header-container">
      <header>
        <h1>Plan.itt</h1>
      </header>
    </div>
    <div class="content-container">
      <div class="navbar-container">
        <div class="first-set-container">
          <ul>
            <li class="nav-item-list">Running</li>
            <li class="nav-item-list">Completed</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <h2>Projects</h2>
        <div class="second-set-container">
          <ul class="second-set-container-ul">
            <li class="nav-item">University</li>
            <li class="nav-item">School</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="add-project-button">
          <button class="add-project-btn">+ Add Project</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="main-list-container">
        <!-- <div class="list-heading-and-button">
          <div class="list-heading"></div>
          <div class="add-task-button">
            <button class="add-task-btn">+ Add Task</button>
          </div>
        </div> -->
        <div id="tasks-display"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Add Project Pop Up -->

    <dialog id="add-project-pop-up">
      <form class="add-project-form" method="dialog">
        <label for="project-name">Project Name</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="project-name"
          name="project-name"
          placeholder="Enter Project Name"
          required
        />
        <div class="add-proj-pop-btns">
          <div class="pop-add-btn">
            <button type="submit" id="pop-up-save" class="">Add</button>
          </div>
          <div class="pop-cancel-btn">
            <button type="submit" id="pop-up-delete">Cancel</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </dialog>

    <!--  -->

    <!-- Add Task Pop Up -->

    <dialog id="add-task-pop-up">
      <form class="add-task-pop-up-form" method="dialog">
        <label for="task-name">Task Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="task-name" name="task-name" required />
        <label for="task-desc">Task Description</label>
        <textarea id="task-desc"> </textarea>
        <label for="task-date">Task Date</label>
        <input type="date" id="task-date" name="task-date" required />
        <label for="task-priority">Task Priority</label>
        <select id="task-priority" name="task-priority">
          <option value="high">High</option>
          <option value="medium">Medium</option>
          <option value="low">Low</option>
        </select>
        <div class="add-task-pop-up-btns-task">
          <div class="pop-add-btn-task">
            <button type="submit" id="pop-up-save-task-btn">Add</button>
          </div>
          <div class="pop-cancel-btn-task">
            <button type="submit" id="pop-up-delete-task-btn">Cancel</button>
          </div>`your text
        </div>
      </form>
    </dialog>

    <!--  -->
  </body>
  <!-- <script src="../src/index.js"></script> -->
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</html>

This is the JS, It is properly connected to the Index.js
export class AddTask {
  constructor(pageName) {
    this.pageName = pageName;

    this.popUpTaskDialog = document.querySelector("#add-task-pop-up");
    this.taskName = document.querySelector("#task-name");
    this.taskDescription = document.querySelector("#task-desc");
    this.taskDate = document.querySelector("#task-date");
    this.saveTaskBtn = document.querySelector("#pop-up-save-task-btn");
    this.cancelTaskBtn = document.querySelector("#pop-up-delete-task-btn");
    this.taskPriority = document.querySelector("#task-priority");

    this.saveTaskBtn.addEventListener("click", (event) => this.saveTask(event));
    this.cancelTaskBtn.addEventListener("click", (event) =>
      this.closeTaskDialog(event)
    );

    this.render();
  }

  render() {
    this.popUpTaskDialog.showModal();
  }

  saveTask(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (this.taskName.value.trim() === "") {
      //this.alertLog("Please enter a task name");
    } else {
      try {
        const taskCardDisplay = document.querySelector("#tasks-display");
        const contentCard = this.createTaskCard();
        taskCardDisplay.appendChild(contentCard);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        console.log("No task display found");
      }

      try {
        const taskMainPage = document.querySelector(".main-list-container");
        taskMainPage.innerHTML = "";
        taskMainPage.appendChild(this.taskCardDisplay);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        console.log("No main list container found");
      }
      this.closeTaskDialog(event);
    }
  } 
}




This is a MERN project and all the relevant files are created, also the project worked well before addition of this function.
All the other required methods are created and they were all working
When I try to add a new task, I get the following error in the console
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild')
    at n.saveTask (main.js:1:11774)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (main.js:1:11479)
main.js:1 No task display found
main.js:1 TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
    at n.saveTask (main.js:1:11926)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (main.js:1:11479)
main.js:1 No main list container found


What should I do to resolve this?

Can you tell to which appendChild() the error is referring?

The const taskCardDisplay should be moved so that it has function scope and  taskMainPage.appendChild(this.taskCardDisplay); should be changed to: taskMainPage.appendChild(taskCardDisplay);

Also, your use of try/catch is not really appropriate. try/catch should only be used to attempt code that may fail through no fault of the developer. Code that relies on network connections or other systems that the developer is not in control of would be where it's appropriate. But here, you're just accessing DOM elements, which is in your control, so you should make the code more robust rather than use try/catch as a generic error handler.

taskCardDisplay doesn't need to be at function scope, it needs to be in the scope of the else block. Remember that let and const are block-scoped, and each try has its own scope.

you could also nest the second try/catch inside the first try/
